# How to compare generic enumeration values?

Tags: scala, scala-2.12

I'm trying to writing a generic max method for Scala `Enumeration` values. I have

```
def enumMax[E <: Enumeration, V <: E#Value](v1: V, v2: V): V = v1.compare(v2) match {
  case x if x > 0 => v1
  case x if x < 0 => v2
  case _ => v1
}
```

but I'm getting the rather cryptic error message

```
[error] overloaded method value compare with alternatives:
[error]   ((that: _1.Value)Int) forSome { val _1: E } <and>
[error]   (that: _1.Value)Int
[error]  cannot be applied to (V)
[error]   def enumMax[E <: Enumeration, V <: E#Value](v1: V, v2: V): V = v1.compare(v2) match {
[error]                                                                     ^
```

Does anybody know what's going on here?  Is there a better way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Connected question: [Deriving a Cats Order for Scala's Enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55940830/deriving-a-cats-order-for-scalas-enumeration)

Comment: @DmytroMitin true, although your original answer is a tad nicer looking imho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a generic `max` like this:

```
def max[T](a: T, b: T)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]) =
  if (ord.compare(a, b) >= 0) { a } else { b }
```

If you want to you can constrain the types that are supported, but it is not clear that this is particularly useful.

```
def maxEnum[T <: Enumeration#Value](a: T, b: T)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]) =
  if (ord.compare(a, b) >= 0) { a } else { b }
```

Answer (score 5):

It's enough to add context bound `Ordering`

```
def enumMax[E <: Enumeration, V <: E#Value : Ordering](v1: V, v2: V): V = v1.compare(v2) match {
  case x if x > 0 => v1
  case x if x < 0 => v2
  case _ => v1
}
```

It was just compiler error message that was not clear.

---

Try

```
def enumMax(e: Enumeration)(v1: e.Value, v2: e.Value): e.Value = v1.compare(v2) match {
  case x if x > 0 => v1
  case x if x < 0 => v2
  case _ => v1
}
```

Comment: Nice edit ;). But that `E` type is spurious, you can just do `[V <: Enumeration#Value : Ordering]`

Comment: @Tim I've got the idea from your answer and from the fact that in actual TS's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55940830/deriving-a-cats-order-for-scalas-enumeration) import of implicit makes difference.

Comment: @Tim yea, that was about minimal change to TS's code.

Comment: Hate to do this to you, but I had to unaccept your answer and accept @Tim 's answer... when I got to actually using your methods outside of my std lib they wouldn't compile. Let me know if you want more details

Comment: @Lasf If this is about using with cats then these details would be more  appropriate in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55940830/deriving-a-cats-order-for-scalas-enumeration) your question.

Comment: @DmytroMitin No cats. Given your top method, `type mismatch; found   : MyEnum which expands to) MyEnum.Value` `required: V`. Your bottom method might actually be fine... haven't tested it yet

Comment: @Lasf Just generics were not inferred `object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
    val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
  }`
  `import WeekDay._`
`enumMax[WeekDay.type, WeekDay.type#Value](Mon, Tue)`

Comment: Fair enough. Upvote restored. @Tim's works out of the gate so I'll keep that as the accepted for others. Thanks a million for your help with all this. Really appreciate it.