# Deriving a Cats Order for Scala's Enumeration

Tags: scala, scala-cats, scala-2.12

I would like a generic Cats `Order` for Scala's `Enumeration`. I tried

```
implicit def enumOrder[E <: Enumeration, V <: E#Value]: cats.Order[V] = new cats.Order[V] {
  def compare(x: V, y: V): Int = x.compare(y)
}
```

but I get

```
[error] overloaded method value compare with alternatives:
[error]   ((that: _1.Value)Int) forSome { val _1: E } <and>
[error]   (that: _1.Value)Int
[error]  cannot be applied to (V)
[error]     def compare(x: V, y: V): Int = x.compare(y)
[error]                                      ^
```

Does anybody know how I can implement this? Thanks

NB, I just asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55940394/how-to-compare-generic-enumeration-values), which I thought would yield an answer that I would be smart enough to apply to this question, but it did not.

Comment: Coud you write how you will apply this implicit?

Comment: @DmytroMitin `NonEmptySet.of(value1, value2, ...)` requires the `Order[A]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
implicit def enumOrder[V <: Enumeration#Value](implicit ord: Ordering[V]): cats.Order[V] = new cats.Order[V] {
  def compare(x: V, y: V): Int = ord.compare(x, y)
}
```

or

```
implicit def enumOrder[V <: Enumeration#Value](implicit ord: Ordering[V]): cats.Order[V] = ord.compare(_, _)
```

Comment: For me in Scala 2.12.8 + cats-core 1.5.0 this line compiles (in an object) only with `import cats.instances.order._`. Otherwise I have compile error from above.

Comment: Moreover, if I replace `implicit def` with `def` it doesn't compile.

Comment: Ok, it's enough to add context bound `implicit def enumOrder[V <: Enumeration#Value : Ordering] = ...`

Comment: @DmytroMitin seems to work for me without the context bound on 1.6.0

Comment: @Lasf For me in 1.6.0 still either context bound `Ordering` or `import cats.instances.order._` are necessary.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I am importing `cats._, cats.data._, cats.implicits._` so I'm guessing one of those covers it

Comment: @Lasf, yes surely, `cats.implicits._` covers `cats.instances.all._`, which covers `cats.instances.order._`.

Comment: @Lasf Actually it appears only version with context bound is correct. `import cats.instances.order._` brings implicit `Order[A] => Ordering[A]`. `enumOrder` declares implicit `Order[V]` so we have implicit `Ordering[V]` which is used in `x.compare(y)` and we have cyclic dependency at runtime. So the code without context bound accidentally compiles but can throw `StackOverflowError` at runtime: `object WeekDay extends Enumeration { val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value }` `import WeekDay._` `NonEmptySet.of(Sat, Sun)` `//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin oh, that's bizarre. Thanks a lot for that. I hadn't gotten to runtime yet, so you probably saved me some frustration there.